# Inconsistent conversion of Float into Decimal in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point

First, take a specific float `f`:

```
f = [64.4, 73.60, 77.90, 87.40, 95.40].sample # take any one of these special Floats
f.to_d.class == (1.to_d * f).class # => true (BigDecimal)
```

So multiplying by `BigDecimal` casts `f` to `BigDecimal`. Therefore `1.to_d * f` (or `f * 1.to_d`) can be seen as a (poor, but still) form of converting `f` to `BigDecimal`. And yet for these specific values we have:

```
f.to_d == 1.to_d * f # => false (?!)
```

Isn't this a bug? I'd assume that while multiplying by `1.to_d` Ruby should invoke `f.to_d` internally. But the results differ, i.e. for  `f = 64.4`:

```
f.to_d # => #<BigDecimal:7f8202038280,'0.644E2',18(36)>
1.to_d * f # => #<BigDecimal:7f82019c1208,'0.6440000000 000001E2',27(45)>
```

I cannot see why floating-point representation error should be an excuse here, yet it's obviously a cause, somehow. So why is this happening?

PS. I wrote a snippet of code playing around with this issue:

https://github.com/Swarzkopf314/ruby_wtf/blob/master/multiplication_by_unit.rb

Comment: Does `f == f.to_d` return true?

Comment: What value does `f` take after `.to_d`? The internal representation is usually quite apparent.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why is this happening?

TL;DR different precisions are used.

Long answer:

`64.4.to_d` calls `bigdecimal/util`'s [`Float#to_d`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/Float.html#method-i-to_d):

```
def to_d(precision=nil)
  BigDecimal(self, precision || Float::DIG)
end
```

Unless specified, it uses an implicit precision of `Float::DIG` which is `15` for current implementations:

```
Float::DIG
#=> 15
```

So `64.4.to_d` is equivalent to:

```
BigDecimal(64.4, Float::DIG)
#=> #<BigDecimal:7fd7cc0aa838,'0.644E2',18(36)>
```

`BigDecimal#*` on the other hand converts a given float argument [via](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L1268-L1270):

```
if (RB_TYPE_P(r, T_FLOAT)) {
    b = GetVpValueWithPrec(r, DBL_DIG+1, 1);
}
```

`DBL_DIG` is the C-equivalent of `Float::DIG`, so it's basically:

```
BigDecimal(64.4, Float::DIG + 1)
#=> #<BigDecimal:7fd7cc098408,'0.6440000000 000001E2',27(36)>
```

That said, you can get the expected result if you provide the precision explicitly, either:

```
f.to_d(16) == 1.to_d * f
#=> true
```

or:

```
f.to_d == 1.to_d.mult(f, 15)
#=> true
```

and of course by explicitly converting `f` via `to_d`:

```
f.to_d == 1.to_d * f.to_d
#=> true
```

> Isn't this a bug?

It looks like one, you should file a bug report.

Note that neither `0.644E2`, nor `0.6440000000000001E2` is an exact representation of the given floating point number. As already [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472933/inconsistent-conversion-of-float-into-decimal-in-ruby#comment68190691_40473007) by Eli Sadoff, `64.4`'s exact value is `64.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`, so the most exact `BigDecimal` representation would be:

```
BigDecimal('64.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625')
#=> #<BigDecimal:7fd7cc04a0c8,'0.6440000000 0000005684 3418860808 0148696899 4140625E2',54(63)>
```

IMO, `64.4.to_d` should return just that.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug. `f == f.to_d` returns `false`, so if `f == 1.to_d * f` is true, then `f.to_d == 1.to_d * f` must be `false` because `f != f.to_d`. The `==` method for `BigDecimal` is intended to compare `BigDecimal`s not `BigDecimal` to `float`. Sometimes the equality will work, but for some `f`s the `BigDecimal` representation is exact whereas the `float` is not.

**Edit**: See [Is Floating Point Math Broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more of an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd assume that `f.to_d == 1.to_d * f` should *always* hold and yet it doesn't. It's as if `f` had two different representations as `BigDecimal`. For me it's insane that this equality doesn't always hold.

Comment: `64.4` cannot be exactly represented. It instead is represented as `64.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`. As there is no exact representation in float whereas there is an exact big decimal representation, there will be a problem.

Comment: You can actually verify this. Set `f = 64.4` and then test `f == 64.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`. It will return true.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. But my point is that casting `Float` to `BigDecimal` should be consistent. If one views `1.to_d * f` as a (poor, but still) form of converting `Float` to `BigDecimal`, then it's surprising that it yields different result than `f.to_d`. And this sure can cause a nasty bug.